# Explosive biology

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My organism live in planet full of water . It has only small percent of land about 5% only. It is big as gorilla. It eats metal ores and gains sustenance from it. My organism developed an powerful defence against predators .  It has power to expel caloric energy in the form of heat and light . How can my organism plausibly do this biologically  ?

Comment: Every weapon should be adapted to the target. What is your predator like?

Answer (score 2):

**Magnesium Sacs**

Magnesium is, simply put, nasty and highly reactive. It is highly unstable and, when exposed to oxygen, will commit to a highly exothermic reaction - that is to say, ignite and put out heat and light. Normally, this is slightly tricky to pull off because even given magnesium's high reactivity, it requires a source of heat to start the reaction. However, [magnesium *also* reacts to water](https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Demos_Techniques_and_Experiments/Lecture_Demonstrations/Burning_Magnesium), reducing it to **highly** flammable hydrogen gas in a reaction that also can heat up the hydrogen gas to the point of ignition. In short, dump some magnesium and water together and you have a  potent source of both heat and light.

Now, the problem is making sure that this doesn't explode within the creature and kill them, which is where the creature's metabolism comes in. Let us assume that the creatures finds stable magnesium alloys in the metal ores it eats. It's body then processes the magnesium alloys, isolates the magnesium, and then puts it out within a kind of enclosed and stable 'sack', ready to be used in the event of an emergency.

Comment: How would the water based organism get metallic magnesium in the first place? Magnesium ore is not magnesium metal. Magnesium metal/alloy will only be common if invoking "a wizard did it".

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how I'm envisioning it. Some naturally occurring alloy that an energy intensive biological process can isolate.